# Pandas melt function using column index positions rather than colum names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

Is there a way to set column names for arguments as column `index` position, rather than column names?
Every example that I see is written with column names on `value_vars`. I need to use the column index.

For instance, instead of:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df,value_vars=['asset1','asset2'])
```

Using something similar to:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df,value_vars=[0,1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select columns names by indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'asset1':list('acacac'),
         'asset2':[4]*6,
         'A':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})



df2 = pd.melt(df,
              id_vars=df.columns[[0,1]],
              value_vars=df.columns[[2,3]], 
              var_name= 'c_name', 
              value_name='Value')
print (df2)

   asset1  asset2 c_name  Value
0       a       4      A      7
1       c       4      A      8
2       a       4      A      9
3       c       4      A      4
4       a       4      A      2
5       c       4      A      3
6       a       4      D      1
7       c       4      D      3
8       a       4      D      5
9       c       4      D      7
10      a       4      D      1
11      c       4      D      0
```

Comment: Thank you, also if I need to declare a single column for argument var_name what should I do?   (Instead of 'c_name')                                                                                                                                 
  df_par = df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[[0,1]],  var_name= 'c_name', value_name='Value')

Comment: @MerveDemirci - Do you think `df2 = pd.melt(df,value_vars=df.columns[[0]])` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it gives type error: in masked_arith_op
    raise TypeError(type(y))
TypeError: <class 'list'>

Comment: @MerveDemirci - But `var_name` is string for new column name, so cannot be used like this

Comment: Yes, you're right I need to give a name of course. Thank you.

Comment: @MerveDemirci - yop, it cannot be set from column name/ all values like `id_vars` and `value_vars` variables, added sample data to answer